# How many 4 by 4 real matrices $A$, up to similarity, satisfy $(A-I)(A^2 + I)^2 = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

So I know the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ must divide $(x-1)(x^2+1)^2$. Since we are working with $4$ by $4$ real matrices,

$m(x) = (x-1)$ or $m(x) = x^2 + 1$ or $m(x) = (x^2+1)^2$ or $m(x) = (x-1)(x^2+1)$.

Do I just do a case-by-case analysis or is there a way to determine which of the four is actually the minimal polynomial?

Also, if it is case-by-case then we would have:

(I) $m(x) = (x-1)$ corresponds to $A$ being the $4$ by $4$ Identity matrix

(II) $m(x) = (x^2+1)^2$ corresponds to the companion matrix of $x^4 + 2x^2 + 1$

(III) $m(x) = (x^2+1)$ means we have two blocks each with companion matrix corresponding to $x^2+1$

(IV) $m(x) = (x-1)(x^2+1)$ means we have one block with companion matrix $x^3 - x^2 + x -1$ and another block corresponding to $x-1$.

Am I on the right track? Is this solution correct?

Comment: Yes. You're right.

Comment: @ZhaohuiDu Thank you for the confirmation. I was unsure.